# Use jasmine to test Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine

I am learning Node.js and Express framework. I am a big fan of jasmine. So I want to use jasmine whenever I can, however, I can't find a good way testing Express with jasmine. For example, how should I test a route in app.js?

If I have this route in app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

How can I use jasmine to test it?

Answer (score 8):

Since Jasmine 2 it is very simple to use Jasmine in a Node.js environment. To test [express](http://expressjs.com/) apps with it, I recommend to use Jasmine in combination with [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest).

Here is how such a test looks like:

**project/spec/ServerSpec.json**

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

describe('Server', () => {
  describe('REST API v1', () => {
    it('returns a JSON payload', (done) => {
      request(app)
        .get('/rest/service/v1/categories')
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
        .end((error) => (error) ? done.fail(error) : done());
    });
  });
});
```

Some prerequisites:

1. Install Jasmine v2 as dev dependency in your project: `npm i -D jasmine@2`
2. Install supertest v3 as dev dependency in your project: `npm i -D supertest@3`
3. Create an initial Jasmine configuration using `jasmine init` (Note: You need to install Jasmine globally first if you haven't done already to run this command)
4. Create a specification ending on "Spec.js" (like `ServerSpec.js`)

Here is how a Jasmine configuration looks like:

**project/spec/support/jasmine.json**

```
{
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "random": false,
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false
}
```

To run your specifications (test suites) simply add this to your [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and execute `npm test` (or just `npm t`):

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine"
  },
```

Comment: if someone face an issue with 
`const app = require('../../app');` ; you need to export an object containing the app. to fix the test error:  `const app = require('../../app').app; `

Answer (score 7):

[Jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) makes it easy to use jasmine with node.js. There are some examples on their site. Another example can be found from <s>http://blog.drewolson.org/post/14684497867/</s> [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140802205501/http://blog.drewolson.org/post/14684497867/)

Comment: your link doesn't

Comment: Thanks for info. Added link to the archived version.

Answer (score 4):

You should try out http://frisbyjs.com/

I haven't had a chance to use it, but as I was looking for a solution to the same problem, this was the best I could find.

Comment: At [Marketcloud](http://www.marketcloud.it) we test our expressjs api deployments with frisbyjs and we are pretty happy with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try [supertest](https://npmjs.org/package/supertest) with [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/).

Here's a simple example :

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
  res.send(200, { name: 'toto' });
});


describe('GET /user', function(){
  it('should respond with json', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/user')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', 'json')
      .expect(200, done);
  })
})
```

Comment: I think supertest could be easyly used with jasmine also, so your suggestion could be helpfull, and there is no needs to connect it with mocha.

Comment: he says he loves Jasmine. he asks for a solution with Jasmine. this answer gives him a solution with Mocha. Mocha is not Jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use supertest with jasmine but you'll just need to manually pass errors.  An issue on GitHub project was opened about this a while ago.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/31

Answer (score 1):

You can try using supertest-as-promised with Jasmine.  It is working for me:
https://github.com/WhoopInc/supertest-as-promised

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]