# Incorporating Jasmine into my Node/Express application

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I want to incorporate Jasmine into my Node/Express application so that I can augment it with automated tests. Here are my requirements:

- I want to define my test suite as an Express middleware within my own structure. A solution that requires me to house my test suite in specific directories is unacceptable.
- I need the results to be returned in something that I can consume on my front end. HTML is good; an object or array that I can parse with Angular is even better. I do not have a command line.

This is the code in my `app.js`:

```
var Jasmine = require('./public/js/jasmine'); 
// middleware that runs the test and returns the results in HTML or array/object.

app.get('/jasmine', function(request,response) {
    response.send(Jasmine()); // or response.json(Jasmine());
});
```

Which package do I use, and what is the code that gives me the result that I will return from my middleware?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jasmine to test Express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910167/use-jasmine-to-test-express-js)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm not looking for a means to test my routes. I want to create a route that runs Jasmine against my Node modules.